# Can anyone tell me the reason for this odd glitch?

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, icons

So, here I was using my Windows 8.1 laptop when I noticed something odd.  My Firefox window was sharing the icon of whatever was next to it on the taskbar.  It sometimes didn't have any icon at all.  Possibly related, the system Save As dialogs are not showing.  GTK dialogs are showing.

Here is a screenshot of the glitch.  You will notice Firefox has the icon of the Windows Snipping Tool, which I had next to Firefox in the taskbar, but hides when a screenshot is being taken:

[image: Glitch!]

Any thoughts?  My theory is a screwed-up array somewhere in explorer.exe.

Comment: Anecdotal: I see this and similar often. It is usually a corrupt OS install and other issues are readily apparent or a sign of a drive dying and thus causing this and similar issues. Also common are empty buttons and notification icons.

Comment: @AthomSfere I don't think anything's corrupt.  I regularly run (built-in) tune-ups and stuff at night and they never show any problems.  I think a reboot would solve it, but it was so odd I thought it would make a good question.

Comment: Localised event that went away after a reboot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a one-time bug.  It's never happened again, and everything was fixed after a reboot.  If anyone has a good theory about it, I'll accept that as the answer instead.